# Echo the variable of i in while

Tags: php, mysql, loops, echo

i try something like this :

```
function userrank($userid){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY atacs DESC");
    $i   = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        if ($row['username'] == $userid) {
            echo 'You are on ' . $i . ' in the general leaderbord';
        }
    }
}
```

On the leaderboard it shows me the rank correctly, but i want to show me on another page too , on the "youraccount" page , for this i try to make this function.
what is wrong ?

Comment: `$i` never changes. you probably want to slap a `$i = $i + 1` in there somewhere...

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you're doing here is counting how many users have an `atacs` greater than or equal to `$userid`'s `atacs`.  Problems with this:

- Terribly inefficient.  Note the database retrieves and sends to your
  while loop an entry for every user, even those who have an `atacs`
  less than the `$userid`.  All but one of these while loop iterations
  does nothing by design.  Lots of wasted time sending data from the
  database to PHP, which doesn't even use it.
- Pulls way more data back
  than is necessary.  You end up with *every* row for *every* user in
  your *entire* `users` table - but your result is just a scalar number
  ( how many users with > score ).
- Actually gives you wrong results
  in the case that your score is tied with others'.  In this case some
  users with the same score may be counted as "above" the user, others
  as "below the users".

Databases are good at iterating over data; it's
   all "locally" accessible and the database engine can make many
   optimizations if you can describe in SQL what you are trying to
   accomplish. So instead of doing it that way, why not just do
   everything in the database?

```
set @user_atacs = ( select atacs from users where id = 12 );
select count(*) +1 from users where atacs > @user_atacs;
```

I've mocked up the table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff9a86/3

This solution essentially just counts the number of users with a higher `atacs` than the current user.  All users with the same score will get the same rank, and the next rank will be appropriately higher, so it doesn't suffer from any of your method's errors.

As a final note, the most appropriate way to do something like leaderboards is probably to precompute the leaderboard periodically and then use the results to show each user's position in the leaderboards, rather than trying to compute it on the fly for each user.  But that's even farther out of scope :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment `$i`. I'm Assuming that the leader board order is represented by the result of your query. So, if true, change your code as follows:

```
function userrank($userid){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY atacs DESC");
    $i   =0; // starts out with an unknown rank.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     $i++; // increment $i here.
        if ($row['username'] == $userid) {
            echo 'You are on ' . $i . ' in the general leaderbord';

        }
    }
}
```

The $i will increment for sure. So, if it is not working still, I'd look to see what the result of your query is. Try echoing $row['username'] and see what the value is and then compare that to the echoed calue of $userid.

Comment: If it is represented by that order Then increment should be just before if statement.... Because he passing a single user id.What is the point in incrementing $i after echoing...

Comment: I was thinking that the IF statement should cause the increment. Otherwise, that is not the user being represented, so why increment the counter? But I see your point. I will edit the answer. Thanks.